# How to detect if peer leave video call by force close app

Tags: agora.io

I'm following Open-Duo sample for android (From AgoraIO Github). And I got stuck in this case:

User A and user B are connecting by video call, user B close app by tap recent and click clear app. so user B close the app but User A still in call but no signal from B.

The video call is still continue but it's one side call.

How can I detect user B leave the conversation by this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If users clear/swipe from recent, you will get a callback called [onTaskRemoved](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#onTaskRemoved(android.content.Intent)) in your service, using this callback you can send a signal to User A before you destroy it.

**Note:** For this, to work you need to move your signaling code to a service.

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of A, under this situation, the behaviors of B between accidentally leave and network down have no difference:

- A will not know B is gone untill time is out.
- A will not know B is gone for what.
- B can rejoin into the old channel once the App get restarted or network is up.